# useParams() can not parseInt to number typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

the `heroid` type is string, I try to convert to number always show error.

**code:**

```
import useHero from '../../hooks/useHero';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'


function Herospages() {
    const {heroId} = useParams() 
   const value = parseInt(heroId)
   const{data,isLoading} =  useHero(value)
...}
```

the `useHero` is my hook from `useQuery`

**error:**

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Comment: Do you *need* to convert `heroId` to a number? Can `useHero` consume a string instead? Can you share all relevant code you are trying to work with what you have an issue using? Can we see this `useHero` hook code? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = parseInt(heroId!)
```

makes your variable non-nullable

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here:

```
const {heroId} = useParams()
```

If you hover over `heroId` i guess it will display you `const hero: string | undefined`

This means `heroId` could possibly be `undefined`

But `parseInt()` expects an `string`

This means: It expects `string` but you pass in `string | undefined`

You need to check first if its undefined:

```
const {heroId} = useParams() 
if(heroId === undefined) return
```

Comment: This would violate the rules of hooks in React since the code would return before all hooks have run (there is a `useHero` hook right after the `parseInt` lint.

Comment: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'heroTypeid'` the new error show at useHero(heroid)